# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Chart Advanced charts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, charts

Is it possible to get this kind of charts http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704599.aspx using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Chart Helper?

when i am passing Presentation XML to helper as a chart theme it is just does not work.

Anything i can do?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you're still looking for an answer to this question. Do you mean is it possible to get a chart that looks like the one you linked to? [Here's](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/03/21/chart-helper-in-asp-net-mvc-3-0-with-transparent-background.aspx) a pretty nice walk-through for one that looks similar, and some example presentation xml. If this is what you're already doing, you should post your img tag, action method, xml string, and any other relevant code. You might just have something out of place.